# Multiple egress IPs for Azure Container Group

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-container-instances

I would like to use multiple egress IPs for an Azure Container Group where each container instance in that group uses one of those IPs.
Something like a NAT gateway might work, but apparently that is not supported.
I also read there may be a workaround with Azure Firewall, but can't find resources that describe this.
What is the recommended solution for my use-case?

Edit: Also noting that our containers are windows-based. Which may add further limitations to our options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Windows containers are not yet supported for deployment in VNET we cannot approach routing egress traffic manually.

**References:**

1. [Virtual networking for Container group-Limitations.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-virtual-network-concepts#other-limitations)
2. [Container groups  and the types of scenarios they enable.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-groups#what-is-a-container-group)
3. [Steps to configure a container group in a virtual network integrated with Azure Firewall.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-egress-ip-address)
4. [Configure IP addresses for azure firewall.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/deploy-multi-public-ip-powershell)

Comment: You can provide your feedback by adding any idea or suggestions here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback